# How do I get my while loop to store its result in an array, and repeat 10 times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I've seen links on stack to other questions that parts of this, but honestly they're all formatted in a way that a JavaScript newbie like me can't understand.

```
var currentMMR = 3330;
var desiredMMR = 4000;
var playerWinrate = 50;

var array = [];

function calculate() {
    //Gets the amount of games you need to win
    var gamesToWin = (desiredMMR - currentMMR) / 25;

    var gamesToPlay = 0;
    var progress = currentMMR;
    var endgoal = desiredMMR;

    var numbersInArray = 0;

    while(numbersInArray < 10) {
        while(progress < endgoal) {
            if(getRandomNumber() >= playerWinrate) {
                gamesToPlay = gamesToPlay +1;
                progress = progress + 25;
            } else {
                gamesToPlay = gamesToPlay +1;
                progress = progress - 25;
            }   
        }
        array.push(gamesToPlay);
        numbersInArray++;
    }

    alert(numbersInArray);
}

//Creates a random number between 1-100
function getRandomNumber() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + (playerWinrate/10));
    return randomNumber;
}
```

What I've done so far, is create a while loop that gets numbers from the variables above, does some calculations with a random number between 1 and 100, and then returns that number.

```
while(progress < endgoal) {
    if(getRandomNumber() >= playerWinrate) {
        gamesToPlay = gamesToPlay +1;
        progress = progress + 25;
    } else {
        gamesToPlay = gamesToPlay +1;
        progress = progress - 25;
    }   
}
```

in an attempt to make it store its number after each run, and only repeat the loop 10 times I did this

```
while(numbersInArray < 10) {
    while(progress < endgoal) {
        if(getRandomNumber() >= playerWinrate) {
            gamesToPlay = gamesToPlay +1;
            progress = progress + 25;
        } else {
            gamesToPlay = gamesToPlay +1;
            progress = progress - 25;
        }   
    }
    array.push(gamesToPlay);
    numbersInArray++;
}
```

When I alert the array out to test it, I get 10 numbers, but they are all the same.

How do I make it so that the original while loop stores repeats and stores a different variable.

Comment: What's happening is a number is being generated, and that number is being saved 10 times. So if I alert the array, I get ("207", "207", "207", "207", "207", "207", "207", "207", "207", "207") for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `while` loop, you need to reset a couple of your variables.

```
while(numbersInArray < 10) {
    gamesToPlay = 0;
    progress = currentMMR;
    ....
```

Otherwise the inner `while` loop already has its exit condition set, and you get the same result as the previous iteration.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/o8ecndas/2/